# Convergence in distribution of random vectors

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, expected-value, weak-convergence

Let $X_n=(X_{n,1},X_{n,2}), \quad n \in \mathbb{N}, \quad X = (X_1,X_2)$ be random vectors with $X_n\overset{D}{\longrightarrow}X.$

(a) Show that $X_{n,i}\overset{D}{\longrightarrow}X_i, \quad i=1,2$

(b) Show that $aX_{n,1}+bX_{n,2}\overset{D}{\longrightarrow}aX_1+bX_2 \quad \forall a,b \in \mathbb{R}$

(c) Show that $X_{n,1}X_{n,2}\overset{D}{\longrightarrow}X_1X_2$.

I don't know how to start. I know that for $i=1$ in (a) I have to show that

$X_n \overset{D}{\longrightarrow} X \Leftrightarrow E[f(X_n)]\overset{D}{\longrightarrow}E[f(X)] \quad$ or

$\underset{n \rightarrow \infty}{\lim} F_n(x)=F(x)$.

Please don't use characteristic functions, we haven't been that far already. I would like to use the definition of the expected value, and I thought using something like $E[f(X_{n,1},X_{n,2})]=E[X_{n,1}]$ but then I still don't see how it converges to $E[X_1]$ in distribution.

Answer (score 0):

Pick either definition of $X_n \overset{D}{\to} X$, and leverage it to say something about (a), (b), and (c).

For example, you know $E[f(X_n)] \to E[f(X)]$ for a certain class of functions $f$. And you want to show $E[g(X_{n,1})] \to E[g(X_1)]$ for another class of functions $g$. Can you write $g(X_{n,1})$ in terms of $f(X)$ for some function $f$? Etc.

If you prefer the other definition, take the two-dimensional CDF $F_n$ of $X_n$ and note that the CDF $F_{n,1}$ of $X_{n,1}$ is $F_{n,1}(x) = P(X_{n,1} \le x) = \lim_{y \to \infty} P(X_{n,1} \le x, X_{n,2} \le y) = \lim_{y \to \infty} F_n(x,y)$. Use this in combination with the given hypothesis $F_n(x,y) \overset{n \to \infty}{\to} F(x,y)$ to conclude $F_{n,1}(x) \overset{n \to \infty}{\to} F_1(x)$.

Comment: Thanks for your response! Can you explain why $P(X_{n,1}\leq x) = \underset{y \rightarrow \infty}{\lim} P(X_{n,1} \leq x, X_{n,2} \leq y) ?$ Is it because the CDF converges to 1 for y to infinity?

Comment: @BillyKlein$:$ Let $(\Omega, \mathcal F, \mathbb P)$ be the underlying probability measure space. Then note that $[X_{n,2} \leq y]\ \big\uparrow\ \Omega$ as $y \to \infty$ and hence $[X_{n,1} \leq x, X_{n,2} \leq y]\ \big\uparrow\ [X_{n,1} \leq x]$ as $y \to \infty.$ Since probability measures are continuous from below the result follows.